# How can I use a neural network to model a quadratic equation?

Tags: neural-network

A lot of examples I've seen about neural network to model mathematical functions are using sin / cos / etc. These are nicely bounded between 0 and 1.

What if I wanted to model something that was quadratic? `y = ax^2 + bx + c`? How can I modify my input data to fit this?

Presumably I'll have only one input (x value) and a bias input. The output will be the `y`. My training data will have negative numbers as well as positive numbers.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can feed any real number into a neural network and it can theoretically output any number, so long as the last layer of your neural network is linear. If not, you could possibly multiply all the targets by really small number.

Comment: So you are suggesting that instead of a Sigmoid, to use a linear function?

Comment: Only for the last layer, and only if you want values that aren't restricted between 0 and 1.